# Storing and "Streaming" from Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to grasp how to store video files. I know I can store .mp4's on Google Cloud Store. However, I have had a hard time interfacing my application to stream these video files.

I have found video URLs like:
http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4

Versus what the file on the Cloud Store is, which probably somehow refers to the mp4 I uploaded (right?)
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/packfeed-e027b.appspot.com/o/Stories%2F0%2FM41WiOceiQTs3ELETIT5evcfsJm1_1520646187885.mp4?alt=media&token=201a831b-c239-4563-8178-cec3c4567212

Is there a difference between these two URLs, one points directly to the mp4, and then the other URL which is a "downloadlink"? is there a difference?

Are there any options to store files in the Google Cloud Platform like this?

Answer (score 0):

Your first link points to the file stored on clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de server. The second link points to the file stored on Google Cloud Storage server.

You can upload your files to Google Cloud Storage, then share the file publicly by checking the box "Share publicly" on the file. The "Public link" appeared will be the link available to public, similar to the second link you posted.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects